# Gutenberg react: I need to duplicate TextControl component on button click

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to duplicate the TextControl on button click. I can do it using allowed Blocks but I want to duplicate multiple TextControl components.

```
<TextControl
tagName="p"
label="id"
placeholder=""
focus = {focus}
className="full-width"
help=""
value={ props.attributes.id }
onChange={ onChangeid }
keepPlaceholderOnFocus= {true}
/>
<button onclick="dupli()">Add more</button>
```

Comment: Are they all assigned the same value? That would be weird.

Comment: yes, The tagName, label, placeholder and help values remain same.

Comment: I was referring to this: `value={ props.attributes.id }`. Typing in one will change them all. I can't imagine that's what you want.

Comment: Right. I want different values. so props.attributes.id1, props.attributes.id2 and so on would be good.